# Moving a panel on its X a certain amount in Unity 5.2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't seem to get this working correctly.
Here's what I have:
Canvas
   Panel(Used for scrolling)  800 * 400
     Panel (Container)
      Panel1
      Panel2
      Panel3
      Panel4
      Panel5
   ForwardButton
   BackwardButton

Given this hierarchy, I want to move the container panel over 1 panel with each click of the ForwardButton.

```
void Update () {
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    if (pressedForward)
        panel.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(panel.transform.position, farLeft.transform.position, step);
    else if (pressedBack)
        panel.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(panel.transform.position, farRight.transform.position, step); 
}
```

I added an object to the left side of Panel and use the Lerp to smoothly move to their. This works great for only 1 panel.

I can't seem to figure out how to get it to move across all of them, one at a time. The best I've been able to get it to move was 1 1/2 times.

I'm sure this is a really simple fix...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You should use **RectTransform**, rather than the Transform:

```
var rt = panel.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
rt.position = Vector3.Lerp(...)
```

Update: just tested the above code, it works in my test, see below animation:

[image]

Comment: I get the same effect I had before.

Comment: make sure you code in Update is called; also log the position in the Update() to make sure these values are properly set.

Comment: Altering the `.transform.position` is exactly the same thing as altering the `rectTransform.position`, as `RectTransform` inherits from the original `Transform`

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks The issue had something to do with the ScrollRect MovementType being set to Elastic.

Answer (score 1):

The `step` part of the `Lerp` is wrong, it is not a constant value, it should be a changing value which is the normalized position (0-1) along the distance you are trying to interpolate. Instead, with the way you've set up `step`, it should work if you use the `MoveTowards(...)` function instead.

```
float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
if (pressedForward)
    panel.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(panel.transform.position, farLeft.transform.position, step);
else if (pressedBack)
    panel.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(panel.transform.position, farRight.transform.position, step);
```

EDIT: and if you want to keep using `Lerp` instead, look at the way Unity docs set up the `step`:

```
float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startMarker.position, endMarker.position, fracJourney);
```